# Converting weather glyphs into SVG files

Tags: svg, fonts, font-awesome, inkscape

I'm trying to use [these excellent weather glyphs](https://github.com/erikflowers/weather-icons) in Inkscape, rather than as a font in a browser. Is there a way I can convert them into regular SVG files that I can import?

Thanks a lot,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually used the [method outlined by Gabi at Helpful Sheep](http://helpfulsheep.com/2015-03-25-converting-svg-fonts-to-svg/). Here is the code I used to split the .svg file into a whole bunch of separate .svg files numbered sequentially:

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print 'Usage: python {} webfont-file.svg'.format(sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit()
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as r:
    lines = r.read().split('\n')
    glyphs = [x for x in lines if '<glyph' in x]
    # for every glyph element in the file
    for i in range(0, len(glyphs)):
        with open(str(i + 1).rjust(3, '0') + '.svg', 'w') as w:
            w.write('<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>\n')
            w.write('<svg width="1500px" height="1500px" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">\n')
            # replace 'glyph' with 'path' and flip vertically
            w.write(glyphs[i].replace('<glyph', '<path transform="scale(1, -1) translate(0, -1500)"') + '\n')
            w.write('</svg>')
```

The biggest problem was that the individual SVGs weren't labeled, so I had to go and manually identify which ones were the ones I wanted. After a while blindly stumbling through the files, I thought it would be a little simpler with a map, so I made a version of the program above that dumps everything to one SVG in a long line so I could back out what file was what:

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print 'Usage: python {} webfont-file.svg'.format(sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit()
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as r:
    lines = r.read().split('\n')
    glyphs = [x for x in lines if '<glyph' in x]
    # for every glyph element in the file

    with open(str(1).rjust(3, '0') + '.svg', 'w') as w:
        w.write('<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>\n')
        w.write('<svg width="1500px" height="1500px" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">\n')
        for i in range(0, len(glyphs)):    
            # replace 'glyph' with 'path' and flip vertically
            x = 3000 * i 
            w.write(glyphs[i].replace('<glyph', '<path transform="scale(1, -1) translate({}, -1500)"'.format(x)) + '\n')
        w.write('</svg>')
```

Answer (score 2):

### TL;DNR

1. Install the 'Weather Icons' font on your system from the link below.
2. Save the svg file below.
3. Open it in Inkspace and now you have all the glyphs to copy and paste as text or select the textbox and click Path > Object to Path, then Ungroup until you have the individual glyphs selected. You can now manipulate them as needed.

---

### Getting the Fonts

Your best bet is to download the fonts from that project's web [page](https://erikflowers.github.io/weather-icons/) and install them in your system. You do not specify what operating system you are using but in most, it is as easy as double clicking a font file and you might be asked if you want to install the font. After this you can use these fonts system wide in programs that accept them (In my case I installed the .ttf file found in the weather-icons-master/font/ folder after unzipping the download from the projects page; I am running Ubuntu Trusty 14.04)

Inside Inkscape you can create a Text box, press Ctrl+U, type the unicode for the glyph you want and then press enter and you will see the weather glyph if you have changed your font to 'Weather Icons'. For example, inside a text box, Ctrl+U, then f00d, then enter will produce the 'wi-day-sunny' glyph (the first glyph in the link provided).

### Turning the Fonts into Paths

In your question you reference turning the fonts into 'regular SVG' files you can import. I will assume that by this you mean paths and groups of paths.

To turn the fonts into paths select the text area and click Path > Objects to Path.

If you have more than one glyph, you can ungroup them until you get to the individual glyphs and from there you can modify, export and further manipulate as you see fit.

---

### How to have SVG Icon Font 'Cheat Sheets' in Inkscape

I have encountered this issue before both with Font Awesome and now looking at this question: I don't want to manually type the Unicode for all the glyphs I would want to use in my asset pipeline. Here is a semi-automated way to get a list of all the icon fonts a specific font family provides. *Warning: I will be using regular expression find and replace in a text editor (Atom) for this*

- Install the font you want on your system.
- In Inkscape create some dummy text by going to Extensions > Text > Lorem Ipsum (I am using Inkscape 0.91 r). One paragraph with a couple of sentences will be fine. Or you can just create a flowed text box and paste any text you desire, *we will be replaceing this soon.*
- Highlight all the text in the textbox and change the font to the desired font and make the font bigger (for Weather Icons I chose 40 and that seemed to work).
- Save and quit Inkscape.
- Open the Inkscape svg (xml) file in a text editor.
- Delete the dummy text in between the `<flowPara></flowPara>` tags
- From your browser, copy the page source of the font page where it lists all the glyphs (link provided above)
- Using Regex, Find: `^((?!\&#x[0-9a-f]*;?<\/).)*$` Replace: nothing
- Using Regex, Find: `^(.*)(&#x[0-9a-f]*)(.*)$` Replace: `$2;`
- Using Regex, Find: `\n` Replace: nothing
- You should now have a single line of text with all the unicode codes for the glyphs in that font separated by semicolons, you can paste that in the between the `<flowPara></flowPara>` in the svg file you had opened, resave and open in Inkscape.
- You might need to resize the font or the flowed text box but now you have all the glyphs in one place.

This worked for me both for the weather glyphs, as well as for [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/).

---

### SVG Cheat Sheet Code (for the 'Weather Icons' font)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg2"
   viewBox="0 0 744.09448819 1052.3622047"
   height="297mm"
   width="210mm">
  <defs
     id="defs4" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata7">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     id="layer1">
    <flowRoot
       style="font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:10px;line-height:125%;font-family:sans-serif;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
       id="flowRoot4136"
       xml:space="preserve"><flowRegion
         id="flowRegion4138"><rect
           y="17.991203"
           x="19.104477"
           height="1023.4542"
           width="715.05328"
           id="rect4140" /></flowRegion><flowPara
         style="font-size:50px;-inkscape-font-specification:'Weather Icons';font-family:'Weather Icons';font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-variant:normal"
         id="flowPara4142">&#xf00d;&#xf002;&#xf000;&#xf001;&#xf003;&#xf004;&#xf0b6;&#xf005;&#xf008;&#xf006;&#xf007;&#xf009;&#xf0b2;&#xf068;&#xf00a;&#xf06b;&#xf065;&#xf00b;&#xf00e;&#xf00c;&#xf010;&#xf085;&#xf06e;&#xf072;&#xf07d;&#xf0c4;&#xf02e;&#xf086;&#xf022;&#xf023;&#xf024;&#xf025;&#xf028;&#xf026;&#xf027;&#xf029;&#xf0b4;&#xf06a;&#xf02a;&#xf06d;&#xf067;&#xf02b;&#xf02c;&#xf02d;&#xf031;&#xf02f;&#xf030;&#xf04a;&#xf032;&#xf033;&#xf083;&#xf036;&#xf034;&#xf035;&#xf037;&#xf0b3;&#xf069;&#xf038;&#xf06c;&#xf066;&#xf039;&#xf03a;&#xf03b;&#xf070;&#xf077;&#xf01d;&#xf01e;&#xf07e;&#xf080;&#xf081;&#xf041;&#xf013;&#xf011;&#xf012;&#xf014;&#xf015;&#xf019;&#xf017;&#xf018;&#xf01a;&#xf0b5;&#xf01b;&#xf01c;&#xf01d;&#xf01e;&#xf064;&#xf01b;&#xf074;&#xf062;&#xf016;&#xf04e;&#xf078;&#xf063;&#xf076;&#xf021;&#xf050;&#xf082;&#xf0c6;&#xf0c7;&#xf07c;&#xf071;&#xf0c5;&#xf0c8;&#xf073;&#xf056;&#xf0cc;&#xf0cd;&#xf0ce;&#xf0cf;&#xf0b1;&#xf075;&#xf03c;&#xf045;&#xf042;&#xf055;&#xf053;&#xf054;&#xf03d;&#xf040;&#xf03e;&#xf047;&#xf046;&#xf051;&#xf052;&#xf0c9;&#xf0ca;&#xf04c;&#xf04b;&#xf084;&#xf079;&#xf07a;&#xf07b;&#xf0cb;&#xf095;&#xf096;&#xf097;&#xf098;&#xf099;&#xf09a;&#xf09b;&#xf09c;&#xf09d;&#xf09e;&#xf09f;&#xf0a0;&#xf0a1;&#xf0a2;&#xf0a3;&#xf0a4;&#xf0a5;&#xf0a6;&#xf0a7;&#xf0a8;&#xf0a9;&#xf0aa;&#xf0ab;&#xf0ac;&#xf0ad;&#xf0ae;&#xf0af;&#xf0b0;&#xf0eb;&#xf0d0;&#xf0d1;&#xf0d2;&#xf0d3;&#xf0d4;&#xf0d5;&#xf0d6;&#xf0d7;&#xf0d8;&#xf0d9;&#xf0da;&#xf0db;&#xf0dc;&#xf0dd;&#xf0de;&#xf0df;&#xf0e0;&#xf0e1;&#xf0e2;&#xf0e3;&#xf0e4;&#xf0e5;&#xf0e6;&#xf0e7;&#xf0e8;&#xf0e9;&#xf0ea;&#xf08a;&#xf08b;&#xf08c;&#xf08d;&#xf08e;&#xf08f;&#xf090;&#xf091;&#xf092;&#xf093;&#xf094;&#xf089;&#xf058;&#xf057;&#xf04d;&#xf088;&#xf044;&#xf043;&#xf048;&#xf087;&#xf0b7;&#xf0b8;&#xf0b9;&#xf0ba;&#xf0bb;&#xf0bc;&#xf0bd;&#xf0be;&#xf0bf;&#xf0c0;&#xf0c1;&#xf0c2;&#xf0c3;</flowPara></flowRoot>    <flowRoot
       style="fill:black;stroke:none;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-linecap:butt;fill-opacity:1;font-family:sans-serif;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:10px;line-height:125%;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px"
       id="flowRoot4148"
       xml:space="preserve"><flowRegion
         id="flowRegion4150"><rect
           y="612.95923"
           x="122.8145"
           height="379.36035"
           width="84.605545"
           id="rect4152" /></flowRegion><flowPara
         id="flowPara4154"></flowPara></flowRoot>  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. It appears to be a much more elegant solution than what I ultimately used, which is a script I found to split everything apart. - Alex